# Foreign keys to primary tables or nested table

Tags: sql-server, performance, foreign-key

In this hypothetical example should the foreign key constraint setup for the `ProductId` and `UserId` columns in the `ProductUserCommentAction` table be referencing the Product/User tables as shown in the first diagram **OR** is it OK for those columns to reference the `ProductUserComment` table as shown in the second diagram?

I like how it's setup in the second diagram as it reduces the spider web in visualizations.

Are there any downsides to this second approach?

[image]

**Versus**

[image]

Comment: Also in the second the key should be (ProductId,UserId,ProductuserCommentActionId).  Otherwise you need a seperate index on (ProductId,UserId).

Comment: Does a ProductUserCommentAction record require a ProductUserComment record? If so, how many Action records can be associated with a single Comment record?

Answer (score 1):

I think the 2nd is better.  Because I guess you should not allow a ProductUserCommentAction if there is no ProductUserComment.